# Spring cloud API gateway for microservices

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, microservices

I want to build a API Gateway for our Microservices developed in Spring boot.
Our microservices includes User, Thing, Group, Alert, Notifications etc...These services are deployed on different servers.

I want to build common gateway for Front end which interacts with these services using `Spring Cloud API Gateway`. I didn't find any simple example which can route my request to any microservice and get back with Json response. Please give me example which does same.

Comment: http://spring.io/guides/gs/gateway/ check this might help.

Comment: You can check this Spring with zuul: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi__router_and_filter_zuul.html or Spring Gateway: http://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-gateway

Comment: content [over here](https://github.com/in28minutes/spring-microservices) can be a good starting point along with the above mentioned spring doc links, as this contains working example.